# Diagonalization differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, diagonalization

I have a problem in solving the diagonalization of this differential equation :
$$\frac{d}{dt}\binom{x}{f} = \left(\begin{matrix} -\frac{1}{\tau} & 1 \\ 0 & -\frac{1}{\tau_{c}}\end{matrix}\right)\binom{x}{f}$$
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Go back to your linear algebra book and check some examples of how to diagonalize matrices.

Comment: The coefficient matrix is already diagonal. What exactly is it that you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

Making the change of variables

$$
p = (x,f)^{\dagger}\\
P = (X,F)^{\dagger}
$$

such that

$$
p = T\cdot P
$$

with $T$ invertible, we have

$$
\left(T\dot P\right) = A\cdot \left(T \cdot P\right)\Rightarrow \dot P = \left(T^{-1}\cdot A  \cdot T\right)\cdot P
$$

now choosing

$$
T = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{\tau  \tau_c}{\tau_c-\tau} & 1 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

which is the eigenvectors matrix for $A$ we have finally

$$
\dot P = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{1}{\tau_c} & 0 \\
 0 & -\frac{1}{\tau } \\
\end{array}
\right)\cdot P
$$

NOTE

Just in case you have not been introduced to the theory of eigenvalues, you can proceed with a generic invertible $T$ like

$$
T = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & t_1 \\
 0 & t_2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and then solve the matrix equation

$$
T^{-1}\cdot A\cdot T = \Lambda
$$

with

$$
\Lambda = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \lambda_1 & 0 \\
 0 & \lambda_2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

arriving to the conditions

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{1}{\tau } & t_2 \left(\frac{t_1}{t_2 \tau_c}+1\right)-\frac{t_1}{\tau } \\
 0 & -\frac{1}{\tau_c} \\
\end{array}
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \lambda_1 & 0 \\
 0 & \lambda_2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

now choosing conveniently $t_1,t_2$ to calcell

$$
t_2 \left(\frac{t_1}{t_2 \tau_c}+1\right)-\frac{t_1}{\tau } 
$$

such as

$$
t_1 = \frac{\tau\tau_c t_2}{\tau_c-\tau}
$$

we solve the problem.

Comment: Hi @Cesareo, thank you for the answer! I don't understand how you pass from p to the derivative of P and how you get the T. Could you rexplain the passage, please?

Comment: @Gmp Included the necessary steps as required.

Comment: This is correct, but I doubt it will help someone who does not realize fundamental lack of basic skills and need to brush up on those. For example *how* you decide to choose that $T$ is what he needs to learn.

Comment: @mathreadler   At this point  we could think about what the better outcome. "Go back to your linear algebra book and check some examples of how to diagonalize matrices" or the proposed answer.

Comment: @Cesareo In my experience, it is by far better to try and establish a habit of backtracking where lack of knowledge first appears than to establish a habit of asking someone else at first obstacle.

Comment: @mathreadler The way of the stones to walk on the water is the work of ingenuity or deception?

Comment: @Cesareo : Why do you ask me and not the stones? Also, it sounds very much like a hardware issue.